# Android -- autoLink

Tags: android, listview, linkify

Is there any way to Linkify a specific TextView that is contained within a ListView?  I tried using `android:autoLink="all"` but that didn't work.  I was getting an out of context error.

Important also to note: the ListView is my second view in the ViewFlipper.

I have also tried:

```
            View mItemView = mAdapter.getView(2, null, null);
        TextView infoText = (TextView) mItemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText2);
        Linkify.addLinks(infoText, Linkify.ALL);
```

Right after the adapter was bound to the ListView and the View was switched.  No luck.

Here is the stack trace:

```
06-03 21:19:25.180: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.app.ApplicationContext.startActivity(ApplicationContext.java:550)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:248)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:216)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6560)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-03 21:19:25.219: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1214):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me: 
http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/linkify-problem-t14779.html

Basically, don't use `getApplicationContext()` when you don't mean it (stealing from the link)

GOOD (linkify works)

```
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, itemList);
```

BAD (linkify fails at run with: Calling startActivity() from outside...)

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mContext, itemList);
```

Comment: Thanks, figured there was an easy solution. I was doing exactly what you had, used this instead of getApplicationContext() and works great. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That stack trace is complaining about the fact that you have called startActivity() outside of an activity context without setting a particular flag. It does not seem to relate to your Linkify.

Comment: True, sorry I forgot to mention that the Linkify works correctly but when you click on say a Phone number and it goes to launch the intent.  It blows up and gives me that.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. and struggled with it for about 4 days.. after which i got the solution.

I will telll you what i did...

when you use Linkify in the onCreate of a class then it works perfectly. when you create a method and try to call the Linkify in it then it does not work and gives you the same error.

if you have to call a different method then please pass you context of that onCreate to it and create the Textviews or others with it.... it seems in accordance with the first answer a little i guess...

Rajesh